# What does 手になる mean?

Tags: grammar

As the title says. I found it on weblio dictionary and it says `ある人がその事に当たる。`, but that doesn't help me a lot, as I can't find example sentences (and the one I have on the book I'm reading isn't too clear as well). Can someone help me please?

Comment: The 集英社国語辞典 has a definition with an example: `その人の製作による。「人間国宝の手になる工芸品」`  And [大辞泉](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0na&p=%E6%89%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B) also has a definition with an example: `（「…の手に成る」の形で）製作の任に当たる。手掛ける。「応挙の―・る虎の図」`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As snailplane basically explained, 手に(by hand)成る(be shaped/completed) basically means "done by [someone]". For example, if an artist made a sculpture, you'd say "ミケランジェロの手になるピエタ (noun phrase) / Pieta by Michelangelo". Similarly, you can use this for a building made by an architect, or a play choreographed by a director.

While its literal meaning is to make something by hand, and that is the most common use, you can use it for things that are not literally made by hand (such as a building) --- in this case, the phrase emphasizes a personal attention to the object by the said person.

I think I see 手による more often than 手になる, but they both mean the same thing.